# Why does this return fail?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, return

`/tmp` of course exist, but `mkdir -p` shouldn't return an error when a directory exist.

So why does the following fail?

```
system("/usr/bin/mkdir -p /tmp 2> /dev/null") == 0 or print("Failed");        
if ($?) {print("Failed");}

system("/usr/bin/mkdir -p /tmp 2> /dev/null");
if ($?) {print("Failed");}
```

From Bash I get the expected `0`

```
# mkdir -p /tmp
# echo $?
0
```

Comment: Please remove the `2> /dev/null` so we can see the error message

Comment: Are you sure `mkdir` exists at that path? What does `type -p mkdir` say in your shell?

Comment: Only related: by using e.g. the `Path::Tiny` module, you can do `path("/tmp")->mkpath` with a nice, pure-perl interface without forking a shell... (https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#mkpath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `/bin/mkdir` not `/usr/bin/mkdir`.  I know this not only because you said `/usr/bin/mkdir` fails and not only because I looked on my (Mac OS X) system, but also because such low-level, fundamental programs are often in `/bin` because they are required to boot a system etc.

By the way, you should not use `system(mkdir)` to make directories from Perl.  I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do it more "natively" and with better error checking.

Comment: Specifically, File::Path has a function to recursively create a path